# ASP.NET Validation Suggestion

Tags: asp.net

Simply, right now I have 8 textboxes going from left to right and a label on the far right.
It's like an employee worksheet for a time table where you put in the times into
each textbox and it calculates time and outputs to a label on the right.

Now, I need to validate numbers in each textbox and 1st textbox is "in" and 2nd is "out"
and 3rd is "in" again and 4th is "out" again and so forth.
Validation tasks would be

- if they're all numbers
- if numbers are between ranges (having user input . instead of : for times in minutes) so  1:39 would be 1.39 and there can't be for
  example 2.61. 1<=x<=1.59.
- after an "in", there has to be a following "out" and cannot be followed immediately by an "in"
- for example, 1st box and 4th box can have some values and 2nd and 3rd could be empty.  However, value in 4th box has to be equal to or greater than 1st box.

I don't know how to tackle this. I need a clean, simple, manageable, scalable and 
elegant programming construct. Is there a way?

I tried validator controls but there's limits. Should I have a function for each 
validation task and call every one of them? (I have a button called calculate that'll start all this).

I imagined this to be a simple solution for an owner
but it's getting very complicated and hectic. Can someone tip in the right direction?
Sorry for the complex rules. By the way, I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and wanted to
see how a guru would tackle this problem.
Please help.

Comment: Can't see the problem. Your "question" somewhat lacks a question mark or a description of the problem. Maybe try to clarify what have you already tried and didn't work as expected... Don't forget to attach the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: I see three question marks, however this is still not a very good question.

Comment: `"having user input . instead of : for times in minutes"` ? It'd be preferable to let them enter a time as they would expect to type in a time, not in a non-standard format you decided on. You'll run into problems.

Comment: I made an answer however question is closed. To cut things short, you need to use a timepicker control like http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ & use a custom validator for point 4 in your ost.

Answer (score 2):

Your description sounds like you're trying to calculate the total hours logged on 4 shifts
InTimeShift1, OutTimeShift1;  InTimeShift2, OutTimeShift2;  InTimeShift3, OutTimeShift4;  InTimeShift4, OutTimeShift4

You should not use numbers in-place of time. For example, how will your employee quickly type an InTime for 2:35pm?  In number, it will be 2.5833333333333333. I don't believe all your users are math experts.

Instead, allow users to key-in the actual InTime and OutTime.

then for validation:

```
Public Function fnbIsValidInputs( pvsTime As String) As Boolean
    Dim vbValidationOK As Boolean = False
    If IsDate( InTimeShift1 ) And IsDate( InTimeShift2 ) And IsDate( InTimeShift3 ) _
        And IsDate( InTimeShift4 ) And IsDate( OutTimeShift1 ) _
        And IsDate( OutTimeShift2 ) And IsDate( OutTimeShift3 ) _
        And IsDate( OutTimeShift4 ) Then vbValidationOK = True

    Return vbValidationOK
End Function

Public Function fniMinutesClocked( pvdInTime As Date, pvdOutTime As Date ) As Long
    Return DateDiff( DateInterval.Minute, pvdInTime, pvdOutTime )
End Function
```

Comment: That is a very good suggestion.